# 2 Minecraft versions on diff laptops using same login

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

I got my son Minecraft on the family laptop and when he got his own laptop got him Minecraft Java (and same for his sister) with the idea for me to play Minecraft with them via Multiplayer. Issue is of course his details are still linked on the family laptop version so my ques is - Is there a way for me to change it to mine?

Answer (score 2):

On the top left of the minecraft launcher there is a profile picture with your account name, it has a dropdown menu arrow, click on that and logout of the current account, and then login with your own account on that laptop